# How to access dictionary values by using elements in the list which have keys of dictionary?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, dictionary

For example I have an dictionary as below

```
demo_dict = {1:{2:{3:{4:5}}}}
```

Now i have the path of the value 5 in the list as below

```
path = [1,2,3,4]
```

now by using that path i want to make it as

```
demo_dict[1][2][3][4] # expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use simple recursion:

```
demo_dict = {1:{2:{3:{4:5}}}}
path = [1,2,3,4]
def get_val(d, _path):
  return d[_path[0]] if not _path[1:] else get_val(d[_path[0]], _path[1:])

print(get_val(demo_dict, path))
```

Output:

```
5
```